# Typescript / Webback / Angular2 WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, amplitude-analytics

Trying to integrate Amplitude Analytics https://github.com/amplitude/Amplitude-JavaScript into an Angular2 project. The following code

```
import { Amplitude } from 'amplitude-js';

private amp = new Amplitude();
```

throws

```
core.js:5574 Unhandled Promise rejection: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_amplitude_js__.Amplitude is not a constructor ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_amplitude_js__.Amplitude is not a constructor
```

Installed the package via npm. There are no type definitions or anything similar, but still - 'not a constructor' error?..

Comment: I can't find anywhere in the docs that you have to use `new Amplitude()`. Either new AmplitudeClient() which is depracated, or you have to do `amplitude.getInstance().`. Also I think the import should be `import * as amplitude from 'amplitude-js';`

Comment: This seems to be working, although I am yet to make it log an event... :) Well, at least I don't have the error anymore. Thanks.